# Cannot download application/vnd.google-apps.site document

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I got this error message while downloading a vnd.google-apps.site document:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Google Docs files. [403]
>   Errors [
>   Message[Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Google Docs files.] Location[alt - parameter] Reason[fileNotDownloadable] Domain[global]
>   ]

with the following code:

```
        try
        {
            var request = driveService.Files.Get(fileId);
            var result = await request.DownloadAsync(outstream);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DownloadFile An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }
```

and got this error

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   The requested conversion is not supported. [400]
>   Errors [
>   Message[The requested conversion is not supported.] Location[convertTo - parameter] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
>   ]

while using Export method:

```
        try
        {
            //tried mimeType with: text/html and application/vnd.google-apps.site
            //**it works if using text/plain**
            var request = service.Files.Export(fileId, mimeType);
            var result = await request.DownloadAsync(outstream);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ExportFile An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }
```

how can i download a site file? thank you.

Comment: As stated in the exception, you won't be able to download a document. You need to export the document into your desired [mimeType](https://github.com/google/google-drive-proxy/blob/master/DriveProxy/API/MimeType.cs)
I tried to use https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export and it worked on my document, I could export it to e.g. text/html. As a result, you get what's inside the document - https://gyazo.com/c14ff162b20fe7bbdd3a6e737a3b2ac3

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can export a document:

```
public async void Test()
{
    var request = service.Files.Export("YourFileId", "text/html");
    string result = await request.ExecuteAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

As you can see, you only need to change `request.DownloadAsync(outstream)` to `request.ExecuteAsync()`. You can get the possible mimeTypes from my comment.

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes, but i hope to export the site page like a word document.

Comment: I still don't get what you want to do, can you explain it? Post an example of a file and show us the result that you want to get.